# How to pass value from HTML option to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I want to pass a value from HTML option to a mongoDB. Here is my code :

```
file: (req, file) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
    const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
    const fileInfo = {
      filename: filename,
      metadata: req.body.meta, // need help with this one :)
      bucketName: 'images'
    };
    resolve(fileInfo);
  });
});
```

And my HTML is like:

```
<select name="meta" id="meta">
              <option value="img-h">Horizontal</option>
              <option value="img-v">Vertical</option>
            </select>
```

how can i pass this value img-h or img-v as a metadata to mongoDB.